# conditional select inside select

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, subquery

```
select t.col1,b.somecolumn t.col2,a.col1,VQ.a,VQ.b,VQ.e,VQ.d,VQ.f,  
   (select t.status as a, p.id as b,p.permit as c, p.des as d, p.error_code as e, p.cause as f
   from table_A t 
   inner join table_B p on t.a = p.a 
   where p.c = 'license' and t.status = 'Fail') as VQ
  from table_A t 
  join table_C a on t.col1 = a.asset_id
  join table_B b on t.somecolumn = b.somecolumn ;
```

When I execute the above code, I encounter the error

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: navigation on column "vq" is not allowed as it is not SUPER type
```

I am trying to do a select inside select.

Comment: Please explain the logic for what you are trying to accomplish.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to return multiple columns from a correlated subquery.  If so, you can do so with a `lateral join`:

```
select t.col1, b.somecolumn t.col2, a.col1, vq.*
from table_A t join
     table_C a
     on t.col1 = a.asset_id join
     table_B b
     on t.somecolumn = b.somecolumn left join lateral
     (select t.status as a, p.id as b,p.permit as c, p.des as d, p.error_code as e, p.cause as f
      from table_A t join
           table_B p on t.a = p.a 
      where p.c = 'license' and t.status = 'Fail'
     ) vq
     on 1=1;
```